# Record application events on remote Docker from current system using JMC command line options

Tags: java, jmc, jfr

Basically I would like to record the application events(JFR data) running on  docker from my current system JMC.

Steps followed:

1. Enabled JFR port on my docker service.
2. Verified whether I'm able to access the docker service's JMS port from my current system and it is working perfectly.
3. when I tried to record the application event from JMC application, I'm getting proper data on dump but when I tried to do the same using command line options, I'm not getting the proper dump.
4. As part of project, we do have a batch file which internally calls the application event. I've created a local jar file which will call  the batch file and run JFR command line option on that jar file but still I didn't get proper info. on dump file.

Does anybody provides any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When using command line options, i.e. -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=dump.jfr (JDK 11 syntax), you need to specify a directory where the file is allowed to be written. By default, it is the directory where the JVM process was started in.

If you mean using command line tools, i.e. jcmd  JFR.dump filename=dump.jfr, there have been problems to attach to a JVM in a Docker container. The 'jcmd' tool can't find the correct /tmp directory where a file is located that is needed to attach to the process in the container. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8228343

JMC transfers recording data from the /tmp directory over JMX, so it can avoid the problem. You could write a Java program that dumps programmatically using the.[FlightRecorderMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/jdk.management.jfr/jdk/management/jfr/FlightRecorderMXBean.html).

Comment: Haglin, Thanks for your info.Please find my comments in below

Comment: The recording should dump to the directory where the JVM was started after 80 s. If it doesn't, it is most likely file access problem. What can you see in the log? You could set loglevel=trace to get additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual process i've followed.

1. we do have a batch file to run the application events on our Docker.
2. I've prepared a java program to run that particular batch file and generated a runnable jar file.
3. Now, I've called that particular jar file using JFR command to get those application event's dump on my system as follows:

   > -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=delay=20s,duration=60s,name=Test, filename=recording.jfr,settings=profile -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=loglevel=info -jar sample.jar>